# Caliburn Micro Xamarin Forms Binding Codebehind

Tags: xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms MVVM framework in my PCL Xamarin Forms.
I don't know how to bind the viewModel from the view in my code-behind xaml.cs

### Example:

In XAML would be:

```
<Label Text={Binding Username}/>
```

But I need to write this in the code-behind so:

```
Label= new Label{
 Text= ....?
};
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

Although this stuff is fairly easy to find on Google I will lay it out for you.

Create the `Label` first then bind the `Text` property.
So use code like:

`var label = new Label();
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("PropertyOnYourViewModel"));`

If you have the C# 6 features available to you, also get rid of the nasty magic string and do it like this:

`var label = new Label();
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(PropertyOnYourViewModel)));`

Comment: It works but I have a problem wrt binding a list because I cannot iterate on listitems, how can I do this? My code:

`var list=new ListView();
list.setBinding(ListView.ItemsSource , new Binding("Houses")); 
foreach (var house in list){}` Houses is not null in my ViewModel but I can't iterate

Comment: If you set the `ItemsSource` you do not have to iterate through it. Set a `ItemTemplate` on your `ListView`

Comment: I have to do something like this:`foreach (var house in houses)
            {
           cardstack.Children.Add(new CardView(house));
            }` Cardstack is a StackLayout and CardView is a ContentView. So i was binding my houses into a listview to have the possibility to iterate on them, but I know this is not a good solution and also it is not working. I'm confused about how to do it